# Magento 2.3.2: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setUseContainer() on boolean

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, error, wishlist

I'm facing this error when i try to login as customer, but when i go back or at Home i was logged in but every time i logout & login back, i face this error, also when i was logged in and go to `My Account` i get this error, don't know why.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setUseContainer() on boolean in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php:127 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(283): Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist->_prepareLayout() #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor)) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(81): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context)) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(343): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context)) #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.ph in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php on line 127

[image]

Comment: are you using any custom method where you call setUseContainer() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think i should add another answer and leave previous answer as it is for knowledge purpose. I realized that i'm missing something. a very simple way to resolve this issue.

i have two overridden files which are causing this error `customer_account_index.xml` & `wishlist_index_index.xml`, i just add `wishlist_item_pager` block to it's right place. Here it is:

**`app/design/frontend/Magestore/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml`**

```
.
.
.
    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="customer_account_view.phtml" cacheable="false">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="wishlist_item_pager"/>
.
.
.
```

**`app/design/frontend/Magestore/theme/Magento_Wishlist/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml`**

```
.
.
.
    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="view.phtml" cacheable="false">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="wishlist_item_pager"/>
.
.
.
```

Comment: awesome working for me...

Answer (score 3):

The code was introduced here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19305

As a fix for:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19292

So just check if you've overwritten the `wishlist_index_index.xml`and have a look if the `wishlist_item_pager` block is present.

Original code at:
https://github.com/webkul-ratnesh/magento2/blob/4a149505a71c883a2c93740d3e4fb5c265a2d267/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml#L16

Comment: Thanks mate, but i have another file `customer_account_index.xml`, which cause this error and `wishlist_index_index.xml` causing theme issue... I posted another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i solved my issue, maybe this is not a good way to solve it, but i've no better option, if you find better answer please let me know.

So their is a file in `/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php`, in this file their is a method `_prepareLayout()`, basically before `Magento 2.3.1` their is only this code.

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Wish List'));
        return $this;
    }
```

After that this method turned into this:

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Wish List'));
        // $this->getChildBlock('wishlist_item_pager')
        //     ->setUseContainer(
        //         true
        //     )->setShowAmounts(
        //         true
        //     )->setFrameLength(
        //         $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        //             'design/pagination/pagination_frame',
        //             \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        //         )
        //     )->setJump(
        //         $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        //             'design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip',
        //             \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        //         )
        //     )->setLimit(
        //         $this->getLimit()
        //     )
        //     ->setCollection($this->getWishlistItems());
        return $this;
    }
```

And the error above cause due to this addition code, So i commented addition code and my error disappeared, I know its not good to do changes in vendor, also I have a overridden file `/app/design/frontend/Magestore/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml`, in this file their is code:

```
some code above...
    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="customer_account_view.phtml" cacheable="false">
        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="item/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </block>
    </block>
some code below...
```

This code needs the `$this->getChildBlock('wishlist_item_pager')`, which is not in `customer_account_index.xml`, and if i try to add or remove (`<referenceBlock name="wishlist_item_pager" remove="true"/>`) this block = `wishlist_item_pager`,but by doing this my custom theme messed up, so i decided to go with old `_prepareLayout()` method.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I had do add the missing block

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="wishlist_item_pager"/>
```

to every block with the class `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist`.